# Why am I getting this error when trying to send data from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a layout like so:

**person_stats.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/row_of_information"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This ListView is populated by a cursor adapter like so:

**PersonStats.java**

```
public class PersonStats extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private Cursor dataCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.lalyout.person_stats, container, false);
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        dataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor();
        String fromColumns = {"_id","home_address","home_phone", ...};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.home_address, R.id.home_phone, ...};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.person_layout, dataCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.row_of_information);
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And the row layout:

**person_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, when I try to send data to this fragment like so:

```
PersonStats personStats = new PersonStats();
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putString("home_address", home_address);
personStats.setArguments(myBundle);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.row_of_information, personStats).commit();
```

I always get the error:

```
UnsupportedOperationException addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
```

I googled the error, but cannot find anything that fixes my issue.

Comment: Please post code of `PersonStats`.

Comment: Where are brackets after getActivity

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I have added all code for PersonStats.

Comment: I seriously doubt your onCreateView() method in PersonStats Fragment. From where you have find that overrided method , It doesn't exist in Fragment class at least?

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature you are supposed to use. Please update you method signature.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Actually, it is. I forgot to copy it into my original post. I apologize for the mistake.